# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF' in sql

Tags: sql, datetime, mariadb, date-arithmetic

what command should I use to make an output based on this problem:

> Display the all values of customers who have joined as members for more than 700 days until today

This is the table that I have created:

[table Customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNbxL.png)

I've tried other references using `DATEDIFF()`, but it's always invalid :

```
SELECT * FROM Customers where DATEDIFF(DAY,customer_join,GETDATE())>700;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL/MariaDB, as opposed to SQL Server, `DATEDIFF()` takes just two arguments, and returns an integer *number of days* between them. We have `timestampdiff()`, which takes three arguments.

Also, `getdate()` is not a thing in MySQL (this is a bespoke SQL Server function).

You don't really need date functions here. I would phrase this logic using simple data arithmetics:

```
select *
from customers
where customer_join < current_date - interval 700 day
```

This expression can take advantage of an index on `customer_join`.

Depending on whether you want to take in account the time portion of `customer_join` (if it has one), you might want to use `now()` instead of `current_date`.

Comment: What if we want to find values ​​based on month and year, for example, if we want to display data that is joined at month = 01, year = 2017?